# VBA Class with Static Variables

Tags: excel, vba

I'm running into an issue. I'm trying to define a couple variables that are used in several methods in a class module.

I keep getting an `invalid outside procedure` error. 
Can anyone point me in the right direction? I feel like it is a scope issue but, I'm unsure on how to validate this.

```
' class file_ops
' attributes

Private pdb_file As String
Private pdb_path As String

pdb_file = "db.xlsx"
pdb_path = ThisWorkbook.Path + "\"

Public Sub open_db(pdb_file, pdb_path)

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=pdb_path + pdb_file

End Sub

Public Sub close_db(pdb_file)

    pdb_file.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Put your variables assignment in Class_Initialize().  I hope this is just a test class not a production one :)

Comment: this is my first foray into VBA. I usually stick with Python or PHP but the client has a specific need that VBA just works for. I'm just having trouble getting my head around the syntax and setup. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You may want to use module not class.

Comment: You can assign values to variables at the "top level" if you precede them with the keyword CONST (for "constant"). This means you won't be able to change the values during code execution. Example Private Const pdb_file As String = "abc.xlsx". And typically Const values are written in upper case, so PDB_FILE.

Comment: Thanks Cindy, that actually makes sense.